# How to filter properties using prefix with BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Camel

Tags: spring-boot, properties, annotations, apache-camel

Is there a way to filter by property prefix when reading in values using @Value annotation in Camel?  I'm using the BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to specify the property files and I've tried setting @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "SlowEndpoint") on the property bean, but it seems to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

ConfigurationProperties and Value annotations were not meant to be used together in this scenario.  After removing @Value annotations, the ConfigurationProperties annotation picked up properties that were named identical to the property bean members.

```
public class SlowEndpointConfiguration extends BaseHystrixConfigurationDefinition {
    @Configuration
    @Profile({"default", "local"})
    @PropertySource("classpath:/properties/local/hystrix/SlowEndpointHystrix.properties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "SlowEndpoint")
    static class Defaults extends SlowEndpointConfiguration{
    }
}
```